# SIGSEGV while adding to QListWidget

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

I have a problem with adding an element to a QListWidget. I have build some frame with QtDesigner and then, I want to add some elements to a list in code. Even when I write:

```
QListWidgetItem* i = new QListWidgetItem("text");
Q_ASSERT(stepsList);
qDebug() << "before";
stepsList->addItem(i);
qDebug() << "after";
```

It prints only "before" and crashes with SIGSEGV. Additionaly, I managed to get such error message with this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6f2a4a4 in QListWidget::count() const ()
from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
```

What is the reason?

Comment: Where and how `stepsList` has been declared?

Comment: If `stepsList` hasn't been initialized before you call `addItem` on it, you're dereferencing an invalid pointer. That'll give you a SIGSEGV.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say. I just realized that I'm making this before calling setupUI. Problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, acceptation is needed so I'll write what was wrong:

I needed to call `setupUi()` first, in order to initialize the `stepsList` as @Timo Geusch wrote.

Solved.